# React setState is not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have added the below piece of code in my react project to set the state with the response of a method. But the state never updated. It is always null. May i know how to set the state here

```
_onload():any{
    this._DataAccessObj = new DataAccess();
    let result = this._DataAccessObj.getRequest(this.props.itemId).then((item:IRequest) =>{
       console.log("item");
       console.log(item);
        this.setState ({
       Request: item
        });
       console.log(this.state.Request);
       console.log("setstate");

   });
   return;
 }
```

Comment: What is it? ReactJS or React Native?

Comment: You know that it's null how exactly, by your console.log? setState is asynchronous, it's ok if you see it null in that console.log. Try invoking the callback of the setState.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) of ReactJS and lifecycle:

> Every second the browser calls the tick() method. Inside it, the Clock
> component schedules a UI update by calling setState() with an object
> containing the current time. Thanks to the setState() call, React
> knows the state has changed, and calls the render() method again to
> learn what should be on the screen. This time, this.state.date in the
> render() method will be different, and so the render output will
> include the updated time. React updates the DOM accordingly.

The last part is important: The actual state object will be update later on the line, not directly when the setState method has been called.

[On the same page:](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
> performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
> should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.